# Embedding Javascript in html document

Tags: javascript, include

I'm trying to implement the following code in a html document:

```
    $(function () {

               $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/projects/img/Bathurst/PhotoGallery.xml", // location of your gallery's xml file
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {


                    $(xml).find('img').each(function() {

                       var location = '/projects/img/Bathurst/'; // relative path to the directory that holds your images
                       var url = $(this).attr('src');
                        var alt = $(this).attr('alt');

                        $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+location+''+url+'" rel="shadowbox[gallery]"><img class="thumb" src="'+location+''+url+'" alt="'+alt+'" title="'+alt+'" /></a>').appendTo('#gallery-ul');


                    });
                    $('<script type="text/javascript"></script>').html('Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();').appendTo('#photo-gallery');
                }


            });
});
```

The code works perfectly when I use it in an external .js file, but I cant get it working when i implement it, it just renders with error in the code.

II'm I missing something and dos anyone have a suggestion to this? The reason why I need to implement it, in case some one wonderes, is that I'm building a custom webapp and the line "/projects/img/Bathurst/PhotoGallery.xml" and "/projects/img/Bathurst/" is dynamic variables.

All answers are very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Please define "it just renders" and "error in the code."  How, exactly, is it failing?  Also, how are you embedding it in the document?  Please provide just enough encapsulating HTML to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should learn the basics of Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic line (`$('<script type="text/javascript">...`) is a convluted and unnecessarily complicated way to run two lines of Javascript.

You should replace it with simple method calls.  (`Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();`)

Comment: Ok, so the correct code would then be $ (Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();).appendTo('#photo-gallery'); ?

Comment: @Prodac: _No, it wouldn't_.  Do you know what the two lines are?

Comment: @SLaks: No I don't, thats why I posted the question in the first place. I'm pretty novice when it comes to js...

Comment: @Prodac: Those are two lines of Javascript that call two methods.  You can call them the same way you call other methods.

Comment: @SLaks: That much I understand :) Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup(); is set to run in the div id "photo-gallery" and Shadowbox.init(); (wich is in my html doc) kicks the whole thing of.

Comment: @Prodac: Then why aren't you just calling them normally? (like the `$` or `$.ajax` methods)

Comment: @SLaks: What I don't understand is how to replace $('<script type="text/javascript"></script>').html('Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();').appendTo('#photo-gallery'); with the method calls (Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();). I'll post the code to jsFiddle.

Comment: @Prodac: I don't understand what you're saying. Why don't you just do it?

Comment: @Prodac: I still don't understand what you're saying. You can just write `Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();`.

Comment: You don't know how to type `Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();`?

Comment: hehe I would say it's more where to type it :p

Comment: As I said in the answer, you should replace your bad line. http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/aQyJM/

Comment: Thank you SLaks! :D I didn't understand, and still don't, how this works without the appendTo('#photo-gallery');, but hey, it works :D

Comment: @Prodac: `appendTo` is used to add HTML elements to other HTML elements.  You're calling Javascript methods, which are not connected to HTML elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a `</script>` inside a `script`.
Change

```
$('<script type="text/javascript"></script>')
```

to

```
$('<script type="text/javascript"><\/script>')
```

Comment: @SLaks: When you say "get rid of it", do you then mean remove '<script type="text/javascript"></script>' from $('<script type="text/javascript"></script>').html('Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();').appendTo('#photo-gallery');???

Comment: @Prodac, I think @SLaks means use `$('<script type="text/javascript" />')` without the close tag.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ says

"Alternatively, jQuery allows XML-like tag syntax (with or without a space before the slash):

`$('<a/>');`

Comment: What SLaks meant was for me to replace $('<script type="text/javascript"></script>').html('Shadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();').appendTo('#photo-gallery'); with hadowbox.clearCache(); Shadowbox.setup();. That works perfectly :)